# I am trying to implement a recursive function in Scala to calculate Maximum value in a List

Tags: scala, recursion, types, max, mismatch

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("List is Empty")
  else
     max1(0,xs)

  def max1(num :Int, x : List[Int]) : Int = {
    if(x.isEmpty) return num 
    else if(num>x.head) max1(num,x.tail) 
    else
      max1(x.head,x.tail)
  }
}
```

I am trying to Implement code to throw error when it gets an empty list as input and trying to get the maximum value of the list in a recursive way using another helper function

> error: type mismatch;  found   : Unit required: Int

Comment: I closed the two functions right?

Comment: Your algorithm has a basic flaw: it comes up with the wrong result when given a list of negative integers.

Comment: Consider using a return type of `Option[Int]` for an empty list rather than throwing.

Comment: What is the advantage? Will there be no error thrown?

Comment: Throwing exceptions breaks [referential transparency](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223329/side-effects-breaking-referential-transparency), which is a very useful property for reasoning about/understanding code.

Comment: Understood the reason. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the definition of `max1` before the `if` statement. 
The return value of a function is the result of the last statement in its body. The way you have it now, the last statement is `def`, and it's result is `Unit`.

Comment: Ok will try placing the max1 definition before If statement. But the max1 return value is Int right?

Comment: `max1` return value is `Int`. But the last statement of `max` isn't executing `max1`, it only defines it.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot Understood the concept and the code is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use user **require()**

For example with this more idiomatic recursion code:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  require( xs.nonEmpty, ">>> Empty List <<<" )

  def max1( num:Int, x:List[Int] ) : Int = x match {
    case Nil => num
    case y :: ys => max1( (if( num>y ) num else y), ys )
  }

  max1(0,xs)
}
```

Then,

```
max(List())
```

returns: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: >>> Empty List <<<

Comment: What is the  line case y :: ys => max1( (if( num>y ) num else y), ys ) doing here?

Comment: y :: ys pattern matches a list (y is the head, ys is the tail), the arrow then allows us to call the method max1 using y and ys as the head and tail.  The if condition just lets us advance the max found value.

Comment: Understood, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use these code to solve that problem.

```
object Maximum {
  def apply(numbers: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (numbers.isEmpty) throw new Exception("List shouldn't be empty")
    max(numbers)
  }

  private def max(numbers: List[Int], maxNumb: Int = 0): Int = numbers match {
    case x::xs => if (x > maxNumb) max(xs, x) else max(xs, maxNumb)
    case Nil => maxNumb
  }
}

Maximum(List(1,9,9,12,34))
Maximum(List())
```

Answer (score 0):

Define

```
trait XInt
case class N(i: Int) extends XInt
case object NoInt extends XInt
```

and on pattern-matching an empty list return `NoInt` and otherwise an `N` instance.